# Why my footer appear twice

Tags: css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Imagenes List", "Images", "Home", new { page = 0 }, new AjaxOptions()
      {
        HttpMethod = "GET", // HttpMethod to use, GET or POST
        UpdateTargetId = "divImage", // ID of the HTML element to update
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace // Replace the existing contents
      })
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have two links in my _Layout, `@Html.ActionLink` and `@Ajax.ActionLink`

A div container for ajax

```
<div id="divImage" class="container body-content">
  @RenderBody()
  <hr />
</div>
```

And a footer.

```
<footer class="container body-content">
  <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
</footer>`
```

My problem is with `@Ajax.ActionLink` the footer appear twice when `@Html.ActionLink` only appear once.

I fixed changing the return for "Images" action to `return PartialView()` or setting `Layout = null;`

But I'm wondering why only Ajax need this fix. And is my solution ok?

My guess is maybe something in the css, but not sure what look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only required when using AJAX because AJAX is the only situation where you're inserting content into an already rendered view. The first view render got the entire layout, and then the AJAX call inserts the layout again.

In the first scenario. Just the main view is rendered, so only one layout.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I see now. HTML render the whole Layout Page, and the @RenderBody part take care of the View(). But when AJAX replace the <div> create a new view, and the view also have a <footer> because is using the Layout. But why the AJAX View() doesn't have the navigation links duplicates if they are also in the Layout?

Comment: That I can't answer. It might be just how the browser renders it. Remember that at this point you have a completely invalid HTML document with multiple `<html>`, `<head>`, etc. tags. It's kind of anything goes at that point.

Comment: Ok then. I will just use return PartialView() for those Action call  by AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Just enclose it in the body section like that (this is the principal cshtml):

-body id="miau"-
        @Html.Partial("PartialView1", Model.partialModel)
-/body-